# Adding Microsoft console (CMD) font in registry does not work with Eastern Asian language for non-unicode programs

Tags: windows, command-line, fonts, unicode

The known registry setting in
    LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont

Allows you to add font by having the `Value Name` to be a multiple of `0` and `Value Data` to be the font name. But this is not the case when East Asian language (e.g. Korean) is used for non-Unicode programs.  I only have `Raster Fonts` and `굴림체` (Korean font) as my option. I have the following values in the registry:

```
0    Lucida Console
00   Consolas
932  *ＭＳ ゴシック
936  *新宋?
949  *굴림체
950  *細明體
```

So I have the fonts for, English, Japanese, Korean, and Chinese.

Under Command Prompt Properties. This is what I have:
[image: Command Prompt Properties - Options]
[image: Command Prompt Properties - Font]

Is it be possible to use other fonts like `Consolas` while still using Eastern Asian Language for non-Unicode programs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fonts have to meet certain criteria in order to be available for use in the console window. In your case, given your East Asian environment preference, Consolas is not going to be an option.

The criteria are all listed [here in this knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q247815), but I'll summarize it in case of link rot (Microsoft loves to rearrange and break all the links):

> The fonts must meet the following criteria to be available in a command session window:
>
> - The font must be a fixed-pitch font.
> - The font cannot be an italic font.
> - The font cannot have a negative A or C space.
> - If it is a TrueType font, it must be `FF_MODERN`.
> - If it is not a TrueType font, it must be `OEM_CHARSET`.
>
> Additional criteria for Asian installations:
>
> - If it is not a TrueType font, the face name must be "Terminal."
> - If it is an Asian TrueType font, it must also be an Asian character set.

The latter part is where Consolas runs afoul for you. Consolas is a TrueType font, but not one with an Asian character set. It doesn't have all the glyphs you need; it's only got Latin, Greek, and Cyrillic.

So you're doing it all correctly. Certain fonts just won't show up in the list as valid options if they don't meet the required criteria.

Comment: _Microsoft loves to rearrange and break all the links_ - Oh, they did it again.